# jQuery or CSS: replacing the ® mark with <sup>&reg;</sup>

Tags: jquery, css

I have this HTML heading:

```
<h1>Time Matters&reg;</h1> (equals to: Time Matters®)
```

I need a way to control the '**&reg ;**' mark either by CSS or jQuery. As far as I know, I don't think it's possible to target '**&reg ;**' with CSS, is there?

Now, if jQuery is used, I need to enclose '**&reg ;**' in < sup > tags, like this:

```
<h1>Time Matters<sup>&reg;</sup></h1>
```

...this way I can target the element via CSS.

I tried adapting [this tutorial](http://adaldesign.com/web-development/superscript-special-characters-reg-jquery) but the code encapsulates all words in < span > tags.

Any idea how to accomplish this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "target"? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A normal Javascript `String .replace()` should do it:

```
$(function() {
    $('h1').each(function(i, elem) {
        $(elem).html(function(i, html) {
            return html.replace(/(®)/, "<sup>$1</sup>");
        });
    });
});
```

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/24/

```
// off-topic
```

I just realized it, wow this looks pretty impressive

```
(®)(®)
```

Comment: Please use "\u00a9" instead of "®". For code compatibility! Of course that's what I meant...

Comment: @Vincent: you are right, but in this case.. I have a hard time to fix it :)

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed, it worked perfectly :). jAndy, I'm just starting with jQuery, is there a way you could explain your code a little? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Vincent: that unicode is wrong eitherway. `\xAE` is the correct value.

Comment: @Vincent: Why use "\u00a9"?... Well, jsut saw jAndy's reply, so, why use "\xAE" then?

Comment: @jAndy, sorry about that, should have been "\u00ae". I prefer 4 letter code point for Unicode but I agree it's a personal choice. @Ricardo Using "®" directly in the code will force you to send your JavaScript with the right encoding and some browsers can be a pain when dealing with JavaScript and CSS encodings. Providing the Unicode code point is slightly harder to read but will ensure no encoding issues.

Comment: @jAndy: no need to use the capturing parens: `html.replace(/®/, "<sup>$&</sup>");` should work just fine in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Javascript function for doing this called replace(). [More info here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

I would recommend assigning the contents of the element to a variable, using the replace function to swap out the symbol for the `<sup>` enclosed symbol, then appending it to the document using DOM

Answer (score 0):

Here, a Javascript solution:

```
var replaceHTMLCharacterEntities = function (expression, tag, superscript) {
    var regex = new RegExp(expression, 'g'),
        iTag = tag.toUpperCase(),
        iSuperscript = expression[superscript](),
        tags = document.getElementsByTagName(iTag),
        i = 0,
        tagsLength = tags.length,
        html = "";
    for (i; i < tagsLength; i++) {
        html = tags[i].innerHTML.replace(regex, iSuperscript);
        tags[i].innerHTML = html;
    }
};
replaceHTMLCharacterEntities("\u00a9", "h1", "sup");
replaceHTMLCharacterEntities("\u00AE", "p", "sub");
replaceHTMLCharacterEntities("\u24C8", "p", "sub");
```

[Here a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/JuantxoCruz/4zy2y58v/)